Failed to connect CHILD_SA | Getting zabbix alerts due to errors with strongswan
We have configured VPN connection from Zabix Server to server name deluxe with the connection named "Zabbix-to-Deluxe"
Please find the configuration as below
conn Zabbix-to-vyatta
type=tunnel
keyexchange=ikev2
authby=secret
left=x.x.x.x
leftsubnet=x.x.x.x/26
right=x.x.x.x
rightsubnet=x.x.x.x/26
ike=aes256-sha2_384-modp1536!
esp=aes256-sha2_384!
aggressive=no
keyingtries=%forever
ikelifetime=28800s
dpddelay=30s
dpdtimeout=14400s
dpdaction=clear
auto=start
reauth = no
rekey = yes
lifetime = 24h
inactivity = 23h
dpdaction = restart
conn Zabbix-to-Deluxe
also=Zabbix-to-vyatta
rightsubnet=x.x.x.x/26,x.x.x.x/28
auto=start
NOTE :

IP's are denoted by x.x.x.x due to security reasons

Please find the logs for what must have gone wrong .
Please help as we are getting alerts triggered as soon as the CHILD_SA is stopped.So we are temporarily restartign the strongswan service each time and the issue goes away for sometime and again the zabbix alerts are generated as soon as CHILD_SA fails.
Please help us understand and resolve this issue
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 05[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 40 [ D ]
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 05[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (88 bytes)
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (232 bytes)
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[ENC] parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA request 41 [ N(REKEY_SA) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA No TSi TSr ]
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/NO_EXT_SEQ
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[IKE] inbound CHILD_SA Zabbix-to-Deluxe{34} established with SPIs cf1fd705_i cf9cda04_o and TS x.x.x.x/26 === x.x.x.x/28
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 charon: 10[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[ENC] generating CREATE_CHILD_SA response 41 [ SA No TSi TSr ]
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 06[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (216 bytes)
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (88 bytes)
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 42 [ D ]
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c10100ee
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[IKE] closing CHILD_SA Zabbix-to-Deluxe{28} with SPIs cb6d6584_i (0 bytes) c10100ee_o (0 bytes) and TS x.x.x.x/26 === 169.48.131.32/28
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI cb6d6584
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[IKE] **CHILD_SA closed**
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[IKE] outbound CHILD_SA Zabbix-to-Deluxe{34} established with SPIs cf1fd705_i cf9cda04_o and TS x.x.x.x/26 === x.x.x.x/28
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 42 [ D ]
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 07[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (88 bytes)
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 08[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (232 bytes)
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 08[ENC] parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA request 43 [ N(REKEY_SA) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA No TSi TSr ]
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 08[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Oct  9 03:13:13 mdm-delux-mgmt01 strongswan: 08[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/NO_EXT

